Wildcard function in Power Automate Desktop
I am receiving a Syntax error when I include a wildcard "%" sign in my SQL statements. Is there another character that should be used instead of the percentage sign?
select distinct
[ItemManufacturerPartNumber],
[ItemOriginalManufacturerPartNumber]
from [EDWDB].[dbo].[Dimension_Product_Item]
where 
([ItemOriginalManufacturerPartNumber] LIKE 'CS.INSIGHT.SOLN%' OR 
[ItemManufacturerPartNumber] LIKE 'CS.INSIGHT.SOLN%')

Removed the % sign and the syntax error goes away. Is there another character I should be using?

What is the error message? That is valid SQL

... at least when using MS products.

It just says Syntax error and thats it

Looks like you need to double them up to escape it
